# Why is the galaxy's dark matter halo a sphere instead of a disk?

Tags: dark-matter, galaxies

I understand that the galaxy is disk shaped because it has a substantial total angular momentum (if that's the right term). If the dark matter halo is a sphere, does that mean that its total angular momentum is zero? If so, why would the galaxy and the halo be so different in this respect?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25504/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15226/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46634/